# take off the top edge of google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have an application that is used in Google Chrome with the following parameters:

```
--new-window
--unlimited-storage
--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required
--window-position=100,100 
--window-size=384,96 
--app=URL
```

When the browser opens, it has the top bar with the close, minimize and maximize buttons, but I don't want the top bar.

I need it to look like the picture.

[image]

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/807610/how-to-run-chrome-in-app-mode-without-window-frame

Comment: does not work, continues with the top bar.